# SFML + WINAPI. помогите корректно закрыть программу

Tags: winapi, sfml

в общем WINApi не владею от слова совсем. но и мне надо то от него совсем немного :
нужно окно со стандартными кнопками и SFML-экран в этом окне где я буду рисовать. взял стандартный пример SFML  и почти всё что надо получилось . Игр не пишу ! Анимация так просто осталась.
Проблема только в закрытии приложения. ну не могу заставить корректно закрыть : нажимаю на крестик окна-оно закрывается , но приложение не закрывается.
При закрытии в консоли выскакивает в зацикливании :
Failed to activate the window's context
Failed to activate OpenGL context:                    .

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


HWND button;

INT B = 100;


LRESULT CALLBACK onEvent(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static HWND hStatic = 0;
    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_CREATE: {
        HWND hbtn1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"this btn1",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 150, 35, hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(1),
            NULL, NULL
        );
        HWND hbtn2 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"this btn2",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 100, 150, 35, hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(2),
            NULL, NULL
        );

        hStatic = CreateWindow(L"static", L"This text",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 300, 300, 150, 20, hwnd, NULL,
            NULL, NULL
        );


        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(wparam))
        {
        case 1: {
            B = 10;
            SetWindowText(hStatic, L"10");
            //MessageBox(NULL, L"press btn1", L"App", MB_OK); break;
            break;
        }
        case 2: { B = 100;  SetWindowText(hStatic, L"100");  }
              //default:
              //    break;
        }
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    // Quit when we click the "quit" button
    case WM_DESTROY: {PostQuitMessage(0); break; }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}



int main()
{
    HINSTANCE instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);


    WNDCLASS windowClass;
    windowClass.style = 0;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &onEvent;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = instance;
    windowClass.hIcon = NULL;
    windowClass.hCursor = 0;
    windowClass.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("SFML App");
    RegisterClass(&windowClass);


    HWND window = CreateWindow(TEXT("SFML App"), TEXT("SFML Win32"), WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE, 200, 200, 660, 520, NULL, NULL, instance, NULL);

    // Add a button for exiting
    button = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Quit"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 560, 440, 80, 40, window, NULL, instance, NULL);

    // Let's create two SFML views
    HWND view1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 20, 20, 300, 400, window, NULL, instance, NULL);
    HWND view2 = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 340, 20, 300, 400, window, NULL, instance, NULL);
    sf::RenderWindow SFMLView1(view1);
    sf::RenderWindow SFMLView2(view2);

    // Load some textures to display
    sf::Texture texture1, texture2;
    if (!texture1.loadFromFile("pica/image1.jpg") || !texture2.loadFromFile("pica/image2.jpg"))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    sf::Sprite sprite1(texture1);
    sf::Sprite sprite2(texture2);
    sprite1.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(texture1.getSize()) / 2.f);
    sprite1.setPosition(sprite1.getOrigin());

    // Create a clock for measuring elapsed time
    sf::Clock clock;

    // Loop until a WM_QUIT message is received
    MSG message;
    message.message = static_cast<UINT>(~WM_QUIT);
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // If a message was waiting in the message queue, process it
           TranslateMessage(&message);
           DispatchMessage(&message);
           
        }

       else
        {
            
            float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
            
            // Clear views
            SFMLView1.clear();
            SFMLView2.clear();

            // Draw sprite 1 on view 1
            sprite1.setRotation(time * 100);
            SFMLView1.draw(sprite1);

            // Draw sprite 2 on view 2
            sprite2.setPosition(std::cos(time) * 100.f, 0.f);
            SFMLView2.draw(sprite2);

            // Display each view on screen
            SFMLView1.display();
            SFMLView2.display();
        }
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
    // Destroy the main window (all its child controls will be destroyed)
   DestroyWindow(window);

    // Don't forget to unregister the window class
    UnregisterClass(TEXT("SFML App"), instance);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

использую Viual Studio. в компоновщике подсистему выбрал Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) . Может надо другое что-то ?

Answer (score 1):

Нет выхода из цикла обработки сообщений. Надо добавить выход по `WM_QUIT`:

```
// Loop until a WM_QUIT message is received
MSG message;
while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
       if (message.message == WM_QUIT)
           break;
        // If a message was waiting in the message queue, process it
       TranslateMessage(&message);
       DispatchMessage(&message);           
    }
```

Непонятно зачем нужна строчка

```
message.message = static_cast<UINT>(~WM_QUIT);
```

первый аргумент `PeekMessage` выходной, т.е. она записывает в него данные полученного сообщения и не читает из него.

Comment: спасибо. выход из цикла стоял из примера: while (message.message != WM_QUIT). я его убрал. с ним нажатие по моим двум кнопкам приводили к завершение программы, а не хотелось бы. нажатие должно только править надпись, что сейчас и происходит ) строчка message.message = static_cast<UINT>(~WM_QUIT); шут её знает зачем. давайте уберем.

Comment: вот , а из-за того что там стояло условие в цикле (message.message != WM_QUIT) и было это message.message = static_cast<UINT>(~WM_QUIT); чтобы сразу отвалиться в случае чего